# Facing Issue in Auto-login process on ORO Commerce

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm, orocommerce

We have generated the new bundle. we need to integrate the bundle extension for our customer.

we need to follow the below steps:

1. we have created the one request URL and that URL hit our system means ORO Commerce and we are getting the request parameters. like below: 
   `{
   "GWTSSO":{
   "Type":"SetupRequest",
   "Name":"Ankit Root",
   "Email":"ankitroot43@mailinator.com",
   "BuyerCookie":"1216541571JK517Q",
   "ReturnURL":"https://prub-dev.gwpunchout.com/cXMLTransform.php?portalSetupID=31",
   "PhoneNumber":"111-222-333",
   "CustomerID":"10"
   }
   }`
2. After this user, we registered to our system ORO Commerce and then we generate the one Loggedinurl like below:

`{"GWTSSO":{"LoggedInURL":"http://orocomroot.com/index_dev.php/punchout/sso_signin/?key=d45873e20f7ff45eccb2f5a73d951e79c784e428:77c51230444be0b3:UZLiEDNZ4ZPR49jTinB3P/bY35G4UBTdjvYqvZS9gTugK8XdbPDjXZDXaVKUR1ltCYA03JkMaIRgnhg0fvrA=="}}`

3. After when customer hit this URL on the browser then this token-based user was automatically login to our system ORO Commerce.

Above step according we need to integrate the bundle extension. First and second step fulfillment but third step, not fulfillment So, please help me out the 3rd step we did not found any solution about the auto-login process. so, please help out on 3rd step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`punchout/sso_signin` is not a built-in OroCommerce functionality.

If you are using [Vurbis PunchOut Connector for OroCommerce](https://marketplace.oroinc.com/orocommerce/extension/vurbis-punchout-connector/), please [contact the Vurbis team](https://www.vurbis.com/contact-us/) directly for the support.

If it's something else, then it's hard to help without knowing the implementation, you should provide more details or debug it by yourself.

### Updated:

To automatically login the customer user you can use `Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Security\LoginManager::logInUser()` method.

The method call would be like this:

```
// $customerUser = $this->entityManager->find(CustomerUser::class, 1);
$this->loginManager->logInUser('frontend', $customerUser);
```

Comment: Hi Andrey,
I have updated the question please check and let me know

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: what need to pass on $customerUser?

Comment: the instance of a CustomerUser entity for the user you want to login

Comment: I have tried this way but we fetching the error
Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Security\LoginManager::logInUser('frontend', $login_customer);

Argument 3 passed to FOS\RestBundle\Controller\ExceptionController::getTemplateData() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\ClassNotFoundError given, called in /var/www/html/oroapp/vendor/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php on line 74

Comment: and how to get the CustomerUser entity?

Comment: Make sure all the namespaces are correct in your custom code. ClassNotFoundError means you are referring to class that doesn't exist. By CustomerUser I meant the entity from a CustomerBundle:
https://github.com/oroinc/customer-portal/blob/4.1.1/src/Oro/Bundle/CustomerBundle/Entity/CustomerUser.php

Comment: How to call this service in our custom controller?
/** @var \Oro\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\CustomerUserManager $userManager */
        $userManager = $this->get('oro_customer_user.manager');

Comment: This is the correct code if the service is declared as public. Otherwise, you should use getSubscribedServices https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/controller/service.html#base-controller-methods-and-their-service-replacements

Comment: This is the symfony basics, I could now write all the code for you, so you have to learn it anyway. Please follow the documentation to know how to work with services. If it's still not clear - you can ask the Symfony community https://symfony.com/community